# How to speed up repeated access to an Object/Class Attribute (x.y notation slow)

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

All,

I am using the PyEphem library, and calling the class methods simply updates class variables, rather than returning the output. I have established that the bottleneck in my program is the line of code that is formatted like

```
v = sat.range_velocity
```

If I remove this line, and replace it with a dummy line `v = 5e3`, the program runs in 2.5s rather than 45s.

So, I'm wondering if there is any way to quickly retrieve this attribute numerous times. I thought about finding the memory address and just loading that value (with some error checking, of course), but it doesn't seem as though that is possible in python...

Here are two screenshots showing the issue. As you can see, the ONLY line of code in the `get_vr` function is to retrieve the attribute
[image: profile results]

[image: code snippet]

Comment: Most likely the `__getattribute__` method invoked `sat.range_velocity` is overloaded and is doing extra computation.

Comment: have you tried to see if `sat.range_velocity` really returns 5e3 and not some other value which makes it run longer?

Comment: The is practically no way this line will make the aforementioned difference by itself. Are you sure `sat.range_velocity` is not a `property`?

Comment: I am 100% positive this line is the issue. If I comment it out, the program runs quickly. I can provide screenshots of profiler if that helps? It gets called roughly 3 million times.

Comment: I've added screenshots to the question for clarification :)

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated